# Expression Engine Categories And Safecracker

Tags: safecracker, categories

I am using EE Core and have set-up a site so that when a new entry is published, you also select a category for it, and on the front end this simply outputs the category name. This works perfectly when you publish an entry from the back end, but I also have a safecracker form and when you post a new entry from that, the category name doesn't get outputted - but the drop down of categories is there and correct. Any ideas what could be causing this?

This is is outputting the name;

```
<h1>{categories}{category_name} {/categories}</h1>
```

And the safecracker form with just the category code;

```
{exp:safecracker channel="new_property" return="property/property-index" }
   <select name="my_custom_field">
{exp:channel:categories style="linear"}   
<option value="{category_name}">{category_name}</option>
{/exp:channel:categories} 
</select>
 {custom_fields}    
{/exp:safecracker}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using "Category Field" (http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/category-field) as custom field or storing category with any other field type.

You should just save the categories and that category field automatically populate category name like:

```
{exp:safecracker channel="new_property" return="property/property-index" }
   <select name="category[]">
{exp:channel:categories style="linear"}   
<option value="{category_id}">{category_name}</option>
{/exp:channel:categories} 
</select>
 {custom_fields}    
{/exp:safecracker}
```

You can try above code. I hope, it would work for you.

Comment: FYI Category Field fieldtype doesn't actually store any data. Categories are stored in native format. It simply alters the publish form and category selection mechanism.

Comment: Yes, I know that. I would like to suggest here just to select a category for the entry and category field will show that selected category.

Comment: I am glad to see your input here as you are developer of this useful add-on.